# MMenu right after body tag

Tags: jquery, mmenu

[image]Is there anyway to move the MMenu nav inside another div with in the header? Due to accessibility, I need the nav to directly follow the button that opens and closes the mobile nav. Right now the nav is interjected right after the opening body tag.

```js
    $("#mmenu").mmenu({
        // options
        offCanvas: {
            position: "right"
        },
        navbars: [
            {
                position: "top",
                height: 1,
                content: [
                    mmenuBookingHtml
                ]
            },
            {
                position: "bottom",
                height: 1,
                content: [
                    mmenuSocialHtml
                ]
            },
            {
                position: "bottom",
                height: 1,
                content: [
                    mmenuPhoneHtml
                ]
            },
            {
                position: "bottom",
                height: 1,
                content: [
                    mmenuSearchHtml
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        // configuration
        offCanvas: {
            pageSelector: ".body-overlay"
        }
    });
```

```html
                <a class="toggle-mmenu" href="#mmenu" aria-control="#mmenu" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="toggle-mmenu__wrap">
                        <span class="toggle-mmenu__bar"></span>
                        <span class="toggle-mmenu__bar"></span>
                        <span class="toggle-mmenu__bar"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
<?php get_template_part('nav', 'mobile'); ?>
```

Comment: could you please share your code?

Comment: Are you using one of the plugins, such as the WordPress plugin, to generate the code?

Answer (score 1):

The MMenu has an [config option](https://mmenujs.com/docs/core/configuration.html):

```
menu: {
    insertMethod: 'prepend',
    insertSelector: 'body'
}
```

This tells it to prepend it to the HTML BODY tag. It is not listed in the [explained config options](https://mmenujs.com/docs/core/configuration.html), but it is present in the [source code](https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-js/blob/master/src/core/offcanvas/_configs.ts). As you can see in the [source code on line 53](https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-js/blob/master/src/core/offcanvas/mmenu.offcanvas.ts), it uses this insertSelector to pick what tag or class to inject the menu HTML near. You should be able either pass in a set of config options with a new insertSelector choice, or at worst, modify your source JS to hard-code a new selector to get it to inject where you want.

BUT, doing so may make the menu behave wonky. The menu uses a fixed CSS positioning. Putting that inside another CSS that also has a set fixed or absolute positioning may mean the menu appears in a weird spot or behaves oddly because it's now inheriting from the parent container's CSS and positioning. It's impossible to tell without testing it out (without seeing all your CSS on your site and how it interacts with the menu's CSS). But you can try and see if it works for your situation. I assume they prepended it to the BODY tag to avoid these possible issues.

Comment: So besides the time it would take me to figure out how to pass a set of config options, it could be even more time to try and fix all of the positioning? So what I am hearing is just build my own.

Comment: passing the config options isn't hard; you do it when you create the MMenu object. It's worth a few minutes to try if you've already implemented MMenu. But if the positioning is visibly all jacked up, then yes, I would abandon it.

Comment: I am working on a MMenu that has already been built. Your saying I would have to create a new one in order to get the config options changed?

Comment: No. Can you edit the source code file of the code installed on your project? That's the easiest. Just change the config object in the source code link above in your files and change the 'insertSelector' option to ".toggle-mmenu" instead of "body".

Comment: I tried changing the insertSelector, where MMenu is being initialized, which is the code I pasted above. The menu is still being appended right after the opening body tag. Do I have to redownload MMenu's main css or js files after the reconfiguration?

Comment: You may need to change it in the source JS files to effect the change. Are you hosting the MMenu files on your own server or via a remote CDN?

Comment: the files are within my theme, so then I guess I need to change the source JS as well.